# PHP telling me to fill in all fields

Tags: php

Okay, so I have a contact form:

```
<?php
$body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Message:\n $message";
if ($_POST['submit']) {
    if ($name != '' && $email != '') {
        if ($human == '4') {                 
            if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) { 
                echo '<p>Your message has been sent!</p>';
            } else { 
                echo '<p>Something went wrong, go back and try again!</p>'; 
            } 
       } else if ($_POST['submit'] && $human != '4') {
           echo '<p>You answered the anti-spam question incorrectly!</p>';
       }
   } else {
       echo '<p>You need to fill in all required fields!</p>';
   }
}


?>
```

And the HTML code to go with it:

```
<form action="" method="POST"> 
<!--PHP Code above goes here-->

<div>
<label>Name</label>
    <br>
    <input name="name" placeholder="Type Here">
</div>
<div>   
    <label>Email</label>
    <br>
    <input name="email" type="email" placeholder="Type Here">
</div>
<div>
    <label>Message</label>
    <br>
    <textarea name="message" placeholder="Type Here"></textarea>
</div>
<div> 
    <label>*What is 2+2? (Spam protection)</label>
    <br>
    <input name="human" placeholder="Type Here">
</div>

<input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

But even when all of the fields are filled in, it keeps telling me to fill in all the required fields.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you want to use `$_POST['email']`, and not `$email` (same with other variables). **WARNING** Inserting unsaniitized user input in the `mail()` functions opens your script open to abuse (ie. sending of spam). [See the notes at the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php).

Comment: Also sort out the indentation

Comment: @EdHeal I had to fix it to make heads or tails of this

Comment: @JohnConde - thanks - too late in the day to fire up my IDE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the values of all the variables that are submitted via POST in the following manner : 
    $email = $_POST['email']

I have checked and corrected your code. It was all good, except that you had to declare the POST variables :

```
<?php
  $body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Message:\n $message";
  $name = $_POST['name'];
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  $human = $_POST['human'];
  $from = 'example@example.com';
  if ($_POST['submit']) {
    if ($name != '' && $email != '') {
      if ($human == 4) {                 
        if (mail ($email, $subject, $body, $from)) { 
            echo '<p>Your message has been sent!</p>';
        } else { 
            echo '<p>Something went wrong, go back and try again!</p>'; 
        } 
      } else if ($_POST['submit'] && $human != '4') {
       echo '<p>You answered the anti-spam question incorrectly!</p>';
     }
  } else {
   echo '<p>You need to fill in all required fields!</p>';
 }
}
?>
```

You should also check if whether the form fields are submitted or not by using isset() and !empty() functions.